# accent indiferent regex with jTable

Tags: java, regex, filtering

I've a Java regex for a `RowFilter` that works as a filter for information shown in a table.

The idea is that I've a table with information in it, and below the table is a text field where I write something and filters the rows only if the row has at least on cell with a regex match based on the text entered on the text field.

I've a class that extends `AbstractTableModel` that's the model that I use for the table. Let's suppose that the class is called `ClientesTableModel`.

Then I put a event in the text field, the `KeyReleased` one, which does the following:

```
private void EventFiredInTextField() {
    RowFilter<ClientesTableModel, Object> rf;
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + jTextFieldFiltro.getText());
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

Already the filter is case insensitive. Any way to make it accent insensitive?

Tried what follows already, but it doesn't works if a cell has a string with accents.

```
private void Filtrar() {
    RowFilter<ClientesTableModel, Object> rf;
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + Normalizer.normalize(jTextFieldFiltro.getText(), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

And also tried at least 20+ solutions that appears here on SO and another sites, with no luck. None of them seem to be working with a table...

Edit 1:

Tried something more:

```
private void Filtrar() {
    RowFilter<ClientesTableModel, Object> rf;
    try {
        Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap();
        replacements.put("a", "[aá]");
        replacements.put("e", "[eé]");
        replacements.put("i", "[ií]");
        replacements.put("o", "[oó]");
        replacements.put("u", "[uú]");
        String regex = "";
        for (char c : jTextFieldFiltro.getText().toCharArray()) {
            String replacement = replacements.get(Normalizer.normalize(Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(c)), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));
            if (replacement == null) {
                regex += c;
            } else {
                regex += replacement;
            }
        }
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + regex);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

It just makes some changes in the regex text before it's applied, with the following idea:

If the filter text is `edit` it will be transformed into `[eé]d[ií]t`, and it will be a regex that's accent indiferent for Central American letters.

However, I'm experiencing one big problem. I've the flag `(?i)` in the regex so it's supposed to be case insensitive. But if a cell has for example the text `edÍt`, the `í` and `Í` doesn't catch the `(?i)` flag, they aren't treated as they should, case insensitive...

A simple solution is to change `replacements.put("i", "[ií]");` by `replacements.put("i", "[iíÍ]");`, but hey... what's the point on putting the `(?i)` flag then?

Anyway, this solution isn't so elegant, and it will fail for other accent types (like `¨`). Ideas?

And `sorter` variable is of type `TableRowSorter<ClientesTableModel>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO doesn't allows more than 30000 characters by response, so, I'm going to split this in three answers.

Part 1/3:

After try and error for 4+ hours, found a way. Not so sexy, but it's efficient and it's a real accent indiferent solution for jTables filtering with regexes.

I'd to modify some source files of JDK version 7 update 7. They're `DefaultRowSorter` and `TableRowSorter`.

I added a extra class called `RowFilterSpecialFilter` for coding simplification.

The modified `DefaultRowSorter` and `TableRowSorter` classes are called `DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter` and `TableRowSorterSpecialFilter` respectively.

`DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter` and `RowFilterSpecialFilter` are in a package called `javax.swing`.

`TableRowSorterSpecialFilter` is in a package called `javax.swing.table`.

`TableRowSorterSpecialFilter` is basically the same as `TableRowSorter`. The only change is that all the ocurrences of `TableRowSorter` where replaced by `TableRowSorterSpecialFilter`, and now it inherits from `DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter`. Modified file source (`TableRowSorterSpecialFilter.java`):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2005, 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 */
package javax.swing.table;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;

/**
 * An implementation of
 * <code>RowSorter</code> that provides sorting and filtering using a
 * <code>TableModel</code>. The following example shows adding sorting to a
 * <code>JTable</code>:
 * <pre>
 *   TableModel myModel = createMyTableModel();
 *   JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
 *   table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorterSpecialFilter(myModel));
 * </pre> This will do all the wiring such that when the user does the
 * appropriate gesture, such as clicking on the column header, the table will
 * visually sort. <p>
 * <code>JTable</code>'s row-based methods and
 * <code>JTable</code>'s selection model refer to the view and not the
 * underlying model. Therefore, it is necessary to convert between the two. For
 * example, to get the selection in terms of
 * <code>myModel</code> you need to convert the indices:
 * <pre>
 *   int[] selection = table.getSelectedRows();
 *   for (int i = 0; i &lt; selection.length; i++) {
 *     selection[i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[i]);
 *   }
 * </pre> Similarly to select a row in
 * <code>JTable</code> based on a coordinate from the underlying model do the
 * inverse:
 * <pre>
 *   table.setRowSelectionInterval(table.convertRowIndexToView(row),
 *                                 table.convertRowIndexToView(row));
 * </pre> <p> The previous example assumes you have not enabled filtering. If
 * you have enabled filtering
 * <code>convertRowIndexToView</code> will return -1 for locations that are not
 * visible in the view. <p>
 * <code>TableRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> uses
 * <code>Comparator</code>s for doing comparisons. The following defines how a
 * <code>Comparator</code> is chosen for a column: <ol> <li>If a
 * <code>Comparator</code> has been specified for the column by the
 * <code>setComparator</code> method, use it. <li>If the column class as
 * returned by
 * <code>getColumnClass</code> is
 * <code>String</code>, use the
 * <code>Comparator</code> returned by
 * <code>Collator.getInstance()</code>. <li>If the column class implements
 * <code>Comparable</code>, use a
 * <code>Comparator</code> that invokes the
 * <code>compareTo</code> method. <li>If a
 * <code>TableStringConverter</code> has been specified, use it to convert the
 * values to
 * <code>String</code>s and then use the
 * <code>Comparator</code> returned by
 * <code>Collator.getInstance()</code>. <li>Otherwise use the
 * <code>Comparator</code> returned by
 * <code>Collator.getInstance()</code> on the results from calling
 * <code>toString</code> on the objects. </ol> <p> In addition to sorting
 * <code>TableRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> provides the ability to filter. A
 * filter is specified using the
 * <code>setFilter</code> method. The following example will only show rows
 * containing the string "foo":
 * <pre>
 *   TableModel myModel = createMyTableModel();
 *   TableRowSorterSpecialFilter sorter = new TableRowSorterSpecialFilter(myModel);
 *   sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(".*foo.*"));
 *   JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
 *   table.setRowSorter(sorter);
 * </pre> <p> If the underlying model structure changes (the
 * <code>modelStructureChanged</code> method is invoked) the following are reset
 * to their default values:
 * <code>Comparator</code>s by column, current sort order, and whether each
 * column is sortable. The default sort order is natural (the same as the
 * model), and columns are sortable by default. <p>
 * <code>TableRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> has one formal type parameter: the
 * type of the model. Passing in a type that corresponds exactly to your model
 * allows you to filter based on your model without casting. Refer to the
 * documentation of
 * <code>RowFilter</code> for an example of this. <p> <b>WARNING:</b>
 * <code>DefaultTableModel</code> returns a column class of
 * <code>Object</code>. As such all comparisons will be done using
 * <code>toString</code>. This may be unnecessarily expensive. If the column
 * only contains one type of value, such as an
 * <code>Integer</code>, you should override
 * <code>getColumnClass</code> and return the appropriate
 * <code>Class</code>. This will dramatically increase the performance of this
 * class.
 *
 * @param <M> the type of the model, which must be an implementation of
 * <code>TableModel</code>
 * @see javax.swing.JTable
 * @see javax.swing.RowFilter
 * @see javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
 * @see java.text.Collator
 * @see java.util.Comparator
 * @since 1.6
 */
public final class TableRowSorterSpecialFilter<M extends TableModel> extends DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter<M, Integer> {

    /**
     * Comparator that uses compareTo on the contents.
     */
    private static final Comparator COMPARABLE_COMPARATOR =
            new ComparableComparator();
    /**
     * Underlying model.
     */
    private M tableModel;
    /**
     * For toString conversions.
     */
    private TableStringConverter stringConverter;

    /**
     * Creates a
     * <code>TableRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> with an empty model.
     */
    public TableRowSorterSpecialFilter() {
        this(null);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a
     * <code>TableRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> using
     * <code>model</code> as the underlying
     * <code>TableModel</code>.
     *
     * @param model the underlying <code>TableModel</code> to use,
     * <code>null</code> is treated as an empty model
     */
    public TableRowSorterSpecialFilter(M model) {
        setModel(model);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the
     * <code>TableModel</code> to use as the underlying model for this
     * <code>TableRowSorterSpecialFilter</code>. A value of
     * <code>null</code> can be used to set an empty model.
     *
     * @param model the underlying model to use, or <code>null</code>
     */
    public void setModel(M model) {
        tableModel = model;
        setModelWrapper(new TableRowSorterModelWrapper());
    }

    /**
     * Sets the object responsible for converting values from the model to
     * strings. If non-
     * <code>null</code> this is used to convert any object values, that do not
     * have a registered
     * <code>Comparator</code>, to strings.
     *
     * @param stringConverter the object responsible for converting values from
     * the model to strings
     */
    public void setStringConverter(TableStringConverter stringConverter) {
        this.stringConverter = stringConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object responsible for converting values from the model to
     * strings.
     *
     * @return object responsible for converting values to strings.
     */
    public TableStringConverter getStringConverter() {
        return stringConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the
     * <code>Comparator</code> for the specified column. If a
     * <code>Comparator</code> has not been specified using the
     * <code>setComparator</code> method a
     * <code>Comparator</code> will be returned based on the column class
     * (
     * <code>TableModel.getColumnClass</code>) of the specified column. If the
     * column class is
     * <code>String</code>,
     * <code>Collator.getInstance</code> is returned. If the column class
     * implements
     * <code>Comparable</code> a private
     * <code>Comparator</code> is returned that invokes the
     * <code>compareTo</code> method. Otherwise
     * <code>Collator.getInstance</code> is returned.
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Comparator<?> getComparator(int column) {
        Comparator comparator = super.getComparator(column);
        if (comparator != null) {
            return comparator;
        }
        Class columnClass = getModel().getColumnClass(column);
        if (columnClass == String.class) {
            return Collator.getInstance();
        }
        if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(columnClass)) {
            return COMPARABLE_COMPARATOR;
        }
        return Collator.getInstance();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean useToString(int column) {
        Comparator comparator = super.getComparator(column);
        if (comparator != null) {
            return false;
        }
        Class columnClass = getModel().getColumnClass(column);
        if (columnClass == String.class) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(columnClass)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter.ModelWrapper that
     * delegates to a TableModel.
     */
    private class TableRowSorterModelWrapper extends ModelWrapper<M, Integer> {

        @Override
        public M getModel() {
            return tableModel;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return (tableModel == null) ? 0 : tableModel.getColumnCount();
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return (tableModel == null) ? 0 : tableModel.getRowCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            return tableModel.getValueAt(row, column);
        }

        @Override
        public String getStringValueAt(int row, int column) {
            TableStringConverter converter = getStringConverter();
            if (converter != null) {
                // Use the converter
                String value = converter.toString(
                        tableModel, row, column);
                if (value != null) {
                    return value;
                }
                return "";
            }

            // No converter, use getValueAt followed by toString
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);
            if (o == null) {
                return "";
            }
            String string = o.toString();
            if (string == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return string;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getIdentifier(int index) {
            return index;
        }
    }

    private static class ComparableComparator implements Comparator {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

In the case of `DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter`, it has more changes than `TableRowSorterSpecialFilter`. Basically it has a extra property, `public boolean accentIndiferent` which starts in `false` and the overrided method `public String getStringValue(int index)` of the nested class `private class FilterEntry extends RowFilter.Entry<M, I>` has been modified to return a string without accents based on the `accentIndiferent` value. Modified source (`DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter.java`):

Answer (score 0):

SO doesn't allows more than 30000 characters by response, so, I'm going to split this in three answers.

Part 2/3:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2005, 2006, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 *
 */
package javax.swing;

import java.text.Collator;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * An implementation of
 * <code>RowSorter</code> that provides sorting and filtering around a
 * grid-based data model. Beyond creating and installing a
 * <code>RowSorter</code>, you very rarely need to interact with one directly.
 * Refer to {@link javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter TableRowSorter} for a
 * concrete implementation of
 * <code>RowSorter</code> for
 * <code>JTable</code>. <p> Sorting is done based on the current
 * <code>SortKey</code>s, in order. If two objects are equal (the
 * <code>Comparator</code> for the column returns 0) the next
 * <code>SortKey</code> is used. If no
 * <code>SortKey</code>s remain or the order is
 * <code>UNSORTED</code>, then the order of the rows in the model is used. <p>
 * Sorting of each column is done by way of a
 * <code>Comparator</code> that you can specify using the
 * <code>setComparator</code> method. If a
 * <code>Comparator</code> has not been specified, the
 * <code>Comparator</code> returned by
 * <code>Collator.getInstance()</code> is used on the results of calling
 * <code>toString</code> on the underlying objects. The
 * <code>Comparator</code> is never passed
 * <code>null</code>. A
 * <code>null</code> value is treated as occuring before a non-
 * <code>null</code> value, and two
 * <code>null</code> values are considered equal. <p> If you specify a
 * <code>Comparator</code> that casts its argument to a type other than that
 * provided by the model, a
 * <code>ClassCastException</code> will be thrown when the data is sorted. <p>
 * In addition to sorting,
 * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> provides the ability to
 * filterInclude rows. Filtering is done by way of a
 * <code>RowFilter</code> that is specified using the
 * <code>setRowFilter</code> method. If no filterInclude has been specified all
 * rows are included. <p> By default, rows are in unsorted order (the same as
 * the model) and every column is sortable. The default
 * <code>Comparator</code>s are documented in the subclasses (for example, {@link
 * javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter TableRowSorter}). <p> If the underlying
 * model structure changes (the
 * <code>modelStructureChanged</code> method is invoked) the following are reset
 * to their default values:
 * <code>Comparator</code>s by column, current sort order, and whether each
 * column is sortable. To find the default
 * <code>Comparator</code>s, see the concrete implementation (for example, {@link
 * javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter TableRowSorter}). The default sort order is
 * unsorted (the same as the model), and columns are sortable by default. <p> If
 * the underlying model structure changes (the
 * <code>modelStructureChanged</code> method is invoked) the following are reset
 * to their default values:
 * <code>Comparator</code>s by column, current sort order and whether a column
 * is sortable. <p>
 * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> is an abstract class. Concrete
 * subclasses must provide access to the underlying data by invoking
 * {@code setModelWrapper}. The {@code setModelWrapper} method <b>must</b> be
 * invoked soon after the constructor is called, ideally from within the
 * subclass's constructor. Undefined behavior will result if you use a {@code
 * DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter} without specifying a {@code ModelWrapper}. <p>
 * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> has two formal type parameters.
 * The first type parameter corresponds to the class of the model, for example
 * <code>DefaultTableModel</code>. The second type parameter corresponds to the
 * class of the identifier passed to the
 * <code>RowFilter</code>. Refer to
 * <code>TableRowSorter</code> and
 * <code>RowFilter</code> for more details on the type parameters.
 *
 * @param <M> the type of the model
 * @param <I> the type of the identifier passed to the <code>RowFilter</code>
 * @see javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter
 * @see javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
 * @see java.text.Collator
 * @since 1.6
 */
public abstract class DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter<M, I> extends RowSorter<M> {

    public boolean accentIndiferent = false;
    /**
     * Whether or not we resort on TableModelEvent.UPDATEs.
     */
    private boolean sortsOnUpdates;
    /**
     * View (JTable) -> model.
     */
    private Row[] viewToModel;
    /**
     * model -> view (JTable)
     */
    private int[] modelToView;
    /**
     * Comparators specified by column.
     */
    private Comparator[] comparators;
    /**
     * Whether or not the specified column is sortable, by column.
     */
    private boolean[] isSortable;
    /**
     * Cached SortKeys for the current sort.
     */
    private SortKey[] cachedSortKeys;
    /**
     * Cached comparators for the current sort
     */
    private Comparator[] sortComparators;
    /**
     * Developer supplied Filter.
     */
    private RowFilter<? super M, ? super I> filter;
    /**
     * Value passed to the filterInclude. The same instance is passed to the
     * filterInclude for different rows.
     */
    private FilterEntry filterEntry;
    /**
     * The sort keys.
     */
    private List<SortKey> sortKeys;
    /**
     * Whether or not to use getStringValueAt. This is indexed by column.
     */
    private boolean[] useToString;
    /**
     * Indicates the contents are sorted. This is used if getSortsOnUpdates is
     * false and an update event is received.
     */
    private boolean sorted;
    /**
     * Maximum number of sort keys.
     */
    private int maxSortKeys;
    /**
     * Provides access to the data we're sorting/filtering.
     */
    private ModelWrapper<M, I> modelWrapper;
    /**
     * Size of the model. This is used to enforce error checking within the
     * table changed notification methods (such as rowsInserted).
     */
    private int modelRowCount;

    /**
     * Creates an empty
     * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter</code>.
     */
    public DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter() {
        sortKeys = Collections.emptyList();
        maxSortKeys = 3;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the model wrapper providing the data that is being sorted and
     * filtered.
     *
     * @param modelWrapper the model wrapper responsible for providing the data
     * that gets sorted and filtered
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code modelWrapper} is {@code null}
     */
    protected final void setModelWrapper(ModelWrapper<M, I> modelWrapper) {
        if (modelWrapper == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "modelWrapper most be non-null");
        }
        ModelWrapper<M, I> last = this.modelWrapper;
        this.modelWrapper = modelWrapper;
        if (last != null) {
            modelStructureChanged();
        } else {
            // If last is null, we're in the constructor. If we're in
            // the constructor we don't want to call to overridable methods.
            modelRowCount = getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the model wrapper providing the data that is being sorted and
     * filtered.
     *
     * @return the model wrapper responsible for providing the data that gets
     * sorted and filtered
     */
    protected final ModelWrapper<M, I> getModelWrapper() {
        return modelWrapper;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the underlying model.
     *
     * @return the underlying model
     */
    @Override
    public final M getModel() {
        return getModelWrapper().getModel();
    }

    /**
     * Sets whether or not the specified column is sortable. The specified value
     * is only checked when
     * <code>toggleSortOrder</code> is invoked. It is still possible to sort on
     * a column that has been marked as unsortable by directly setting the sort
     * keys. The default is true.
     *
     * @param column the column to enable or disable sorting on, in terms of the
     * underlying model
     * @param sortable whether or not the specified column is sortable
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if <code>column</code> is outside the
     * range of the model
     * @see #toggleSortOrder
     * @see #setSortKeys
     */
    public void setSortable(int column, boolean sortable) {
        checkColumn(column);
        if (isSortable == null) {
            isSortable = new boolean[getModelWrapper().getColumnCount()];
            for (int i = isSortable.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                isSortable[i] = true;
            }
        }
        isSortable[column] = sortable;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the specified column is sortable; otherwise, false.
     *
     * @param column the column to check sorting for, in terms of the underlying
     * model
     * @return true if the column is sortable
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if column is outside the range of the
     * underlying model
     */
    public boolean isSortable(int column) {
        checkColumn(column);
        return (isSortable == null) ? true : isSortable[column];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sort keys. This creates a copy of the supplied {@code List};
     * subsequent changes to the supplied {@code List} do not effect this
     * {@code DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter}. If the sort keys have changed this
     * triggers a sort.
     *
     * @param sortKeys the new <code>SortKeys</code>; <code>null</code> is a
     * shorthand for specifying an empty list, indicating that the view should
     * be unsorted
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any of the values in
     * <code>sortKeys</code> are null or have a column index outside the range
     * of the model
     */
    @Override
    public void setSortKeys(List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys) {
        List<SortKey> old = this.sortKeys;
        if (sortKeys != null && sortKeys.size() > 0) {
            int max = getModelWrapper().getColumnCount();
            for (SortKey key : sortKeys) {
                if (key == null || key.getColumn() < 0
                        || key.getColumn() >= max) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid SortKey");
                }
            }
            this.sortKeys = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                    new ArrayList<>(sortKeys));
        } else {
            this.sortKeys = Collections.emptyList();
        }
        if (!this.sortKeys.equals(old)) {
            fireSortOrderChanged();
            if (viewToModel == null) {
                // Currently unsorted, use sort so that internal fields
                // are correctly set.
                sort();
            } else {
                sortExistingData();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current sort keys. This returns an unmodifiable
     * {@code non-null List}. If you need to change the sort keys, make a copy
     * of the returned {@code List}, mutate the copy and invoke
     * {@code setSortKeys} with the new list.
     *
     * @return the current sort order
     */
    @Override
    public List<? extends SortKey> getSortKeys() {
        return sortKeys;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the maximum number of sort keys. The number of sort keys determines
     * how equal values are resolved when sorting. For example, assume a table
     * row sorter is created and
     * <code>setMaxSortKeys(2)</code> is invoked on it. The user clicks the
     * header for column 1, causing the table rows to be sorted based on the
     * items in column 1. Next, the user clicks the header for column 2, causing
     * the table to be sorted based on the items in column 2; if any items in
     * column 2 are equal, then those particular rows are ordered based on the
     * items in column 1. In this case, we say that the rows are primarily
     * sorted on column 2, and secondarily on column 1. If the user then clicks
     * the header for column 3, then the items are primarily sorted on column 3
     * and secondarily sorted on column 2. Because the maximum number of sort
     * keys has been set to 2 with
     * <code>setMaxSortKeys</code>, column 1 no longer has an effect on the
     * order. <p> The maximum number of sort keys is enforced by
     * <code>toggleSortOrder</code>. You can specify more sort keys by invoking
     * <code>setSortKeys</code> directly and they will all be honored. However
     * if
     * <code>toggleSortOrder</code> is subsequently invoked the maximum number
     * of sort keys will be enforced. The default value is 3.
     *
     * @param max the maximum number of sort keys
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>max</code> &lt; 1
     */
    public void setMaxSortKeys(int max) {
        if (max < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid max");
        }
        maxSortKeys = max;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the maximum number of sort keys.
     *
     * @return the maximum number of sort keys
     */
    public int getMaxSortKeys() {
        return maxSortKeys;
    }

    /**
     * If true, specifies that a sort should happen when the underlying model is
     * updated (
     * <code>rowsUpdated</code> is invoked). For example, if this is true and
     * the user edits an entry the location of that item in the view may change.
     * The default is false.
     *
     * @param sortsOnUpdates whether or not to sort on update events
     */
    public void setSortsOnUpdates(boolean sortsOnUpdates) {
        this.sortsOnUpdates = sortsOnUpdates;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if a sort should happen when the underlying model is
     * updated; otherwise, returns false.
     *
     * @return whether or not to sort when the model is updated
     */
    public boolean getSortsOnUpdates() {
        return sortsOnUpdates;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the filterInclude that determines which rows, if any, should be
     * hidden from the view. The filterInclude is applied before sorting. A
     * value of
     * <code>null</code> indicates all values from the model should be included.
     * <p>
     * <code>RowFilter</code>'s
     * <code>include</code> method is passed an
     * <code>Entry</code> that wraps the underlying model. The number of columns
     * in the
     * <code>Entry</code> corresponds to the number of columns in the
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code>. The identifier comes from the
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code> as well. <p> This method triggers a sort.
     *
     * @param filterInclude the filterInclude used to determine what entries
     * should be included
     */
    public void setRowFilter(RowFilter<? super M, ? super I> filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
        sort();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the filterInclude that determines which rows, if any, should be
     * hidden from view.
     *
     * @return the filterInclude
     */
    public RowFilter<? super M, ? super I> getRowFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    /**
     * Reverses the sort order from ascending to descending (or descending to
     * ascending) if the specified column is already the primary sorted column;
     * otherwise, makes the specified column the primary sorted column, with an
     * ascending sort order. If the specified column is not sortable, this
     * method has no effect.
     *
     * @param column index of the column to make the primary sorted column, in
     * terms of the underlying model
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     * @see #setSortable(int,boolean)
     * @see #setMaxSortKeys(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void toggleSortOrder(int column) {
        checkColumn(column);
        if (isSortable(column)) {
            List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<>(getSortKeys());
            SortKey sortKey;
            int sortIndex;
            for (sortIndex = keys.size() - 1; sortIndex >= 0; sortIndex--) {
                if (keys.get(sortIndex).getColumn() == column) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sortIndex == -1) {
                // Key doesn't exist
                sortKey = new SortKey(column, SortOrder.ASCENDING);
                keys.add(0, sortKey);
            } else if (sortIndex == 0) {
                // It's the primary sorting key, toggle it
                keys.set(0, toggle(keys.get(0)));
            } else {
                // It's not the first, but was sorted on, remove old
                // entry, insert as first with ascending.
                keys.remove(sortIndex);
                keys.add(0, new SortKey(column, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
            }
            if (keys.size() > getMaxSortKeys()) {
                keys = keys.subList(0, getMaxSortKeys());
            }
            setSortKeys(keys);
        }
    }

    private SortKey toggle(SortKey key) {
        if (key.getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING) {
            return new SortKey(key.getColumn(), SortOrder.DESCENDING);
        }
        return new SortKey(key.getColumn(), SortOrder.ASCENDING);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int convertRowIndexToView(int index) {
        if (modelToView == null) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= getModelWrapper().getRowCount()) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index");
            }
            return index;
        }
        return modelToView[index];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int convertRowIndexToModel(int index) {
        if (viewToModel == null) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= getModelWrapper().getRowCount()) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index");
            }
            return index;
        }
        return viewToModel[index].modelIndex;
    }

    private boolean isUnsorted() {
        List<? extends SortKey> keys = getSortKeys();
        int keySize = keys.size();
        return (keySize == 0 || keys.get(0).getSortOrder()
                == SortOrder.UNSORTED);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the existing filtered data. This should only be used if the
     * filterInclude hasn't changed.
     */
    private void sortExistingData() {
        int[] lastViewToModel = getViewToModelAsInts(viewToModel);

        updateUseToString();
        cacheSortKeys(getSortKeys());

        if (isUnsorted()) {
            if (getRowFilter() == null) {
                viewToModel = null;
                modelToView = null;
            } else {
                int included = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < modelToView.length; i++) {
                    if (modelToView[i] != -1) {
                        viewToModel[included].modelIndex = i;
                        modelToView[i] = included++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // sort the data
            Arrays.sort(viewToModel);

            // Update the modelToView array
            setModelToViewFromViewToModel(false);
        }
        fireRowSorterChanged(lastViewToModel);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts and filters the rows in the view based on the sort keys of the
     * columns currently being sorted and the filterInclude, if any, associated
     * with this sorter. An empty
     * <code>sortKeys</code> list indicates that the view should unsorted, the
     * same as the model.
     *
     * @see #setRowFilter
     * @see #setSortKeys
     */
    public void sort() {
        sorted = true;
        int[] lastViewToModel = getViewToModelAsInts(viewToModel);
        updateUseToString();
        if (isUnsorted()) {
            // Unsorted
            cachedSortKeys = new SortKey[0];
            if (getRowFilter() == null) {
                // No filterInclude & unsorted
                if (viewToModel != null) {
                    // sorted -> unsorted
                    viewToModel = null;
                    modelToView = null;
                } else {
                    // unsorted -> unsorted
                    // No need to do anything.
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                // There is filterInclude, reset mappings
                initializeFilteredMapping();
            }
        } else {
            cacheSortKeys(getSortKeys());

            if (getRowFilter() != null) {
                initializeFilteredMapping();
            } else {
                createModelToView(getModelWrapper().getRowCount());
                createViewToModel(getModelWrapper().getRowCount());
            }

            // sort them
            Arrays.sort(viewToModel);

            // Update the modelToView array
            setModelToViewFromViewToModel(false);
        }
        fireRowSorterChanged(lastViewToModel);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the useToString mapping before a sort.
     */
    private void updateUseToString() {
        int i = getModelWrapper().getColumnCount();
        if (useToString == null || useToString.length != i) {
            useToString = new boolean[i];
        }
        for (--i; i >= 0; i--) {
            useToString[i] = useToString(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the viewToModel and modelToView mappings based on the current
     * Filter.
     */
    private void initializeFilteredMapping() {
        int rowCount = getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
        int i, j;
        int excludedCount = 0;

        // Update model -> view
        createModelToView(rowCount);
        for (i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            if (include(i)) {
                modelToView[i] = i - excludedCount;
            } else {
                modelToView[i] = -1;
                excludedCount++;
            }
        }

        // Update view -> model
        createViewToModel(rowCount - excludedCount);
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            if (modelToView[i] != -1) {
                viewToModel[j++].modelIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes sure the modelToView array is of size rowCount.
     */
    private void createModelToView(int rowCount) {
        if (modelToView == null || modelToView.length != rowCount) {
            modelToView = new int[rowCount];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resets the viewToModel array to be of size rowCount.
     */
    private void createViewToModel(int rowCount) {
        int recreateFrom = 0;
        if (viewToModel != null) {
            recreateFrom = Math.min(rowCount, viewToModel.length);
            if (viewToModel.length != rowCount) {
                Row[] oldViewToModel = viewToModel;
                viewToModel = new Row[rowCount];
                System.arraycopy(oldViewToModel, 0, viewToModel,
                        0, recreateFrom);
            }
        } else {
            viewToModel = new Row[rowCount];
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < recreateFrom; i++) {
            viewToModel[i].modelIndex = i;
        }
        for (i = recreateFrom; i < rowCount; i++) {
            viewToModel[i] = new Row(this, i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Caches the sort keys before a sort.
     */
    private void cacheSortKeys(List<? extends SortKey> keys) {
        int keySize = keys.size();
        sortComparators = new Comparator[keySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < keySize; i++) {
            sortComparators[i] = getComparator0(keys.get(i).getColumn());
        }
        cachedSortKeys = keys.toArray(new SortKey[keySize]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether or not to convert the value to a string before doing
     * comparisons when sorting. If true
     * <code>ModelWrapper.getStringValueAt</code> will be used, otherwise
     * <code>ModelWrapper.getValueAt</code> will be used. It is up to
     * subclasses, such as
     * <code>TableRowSorter</code>, to honor this value in their
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code> implementation.
     *
     * @param column the index of the column to test, in terms of the underlying
```

Answer (score 0):

SO doesn't allows more than 30000 characters by response, so, I'm going to split this in three answers.

Part 3/3:

```
     * model
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if <code>column</code> is not valid
     */
    protected boolean useToString(int column) {
        return (getComparator(column) == null);
    }

    /**
     * Refreshes the modelToView mapping from that of viewToModel. If
     * <code>unsetFirst</code> is true, all indices in modelToView are first set
     * to -1.
     */
    private void setModelToViewFromViewToModel(boolean unsetFirst) {
        int i;
        if (unsetFirst) {
            for (i = modelToView.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                modelToView[i] = -1;
            }
        }
        for (i = viewToModel.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            modelToView[viewToModel[i].modelIndex] = i;
        }
    }

    private int[] getViewToModelAsInts(Row[] viewToModel) {
        if (viewToModel != null) {
            int[] viewToModelI = new int[viewToModel.length];
            for (int i = viewToModel.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                viewToModelI[i] = viewToModel[i].modelIndex;
            }
            return viewToModelI;
        }
        return new int[0];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the
     * <code>Comparator</code> to use when sorting the specified column. This
     * does not trigger a sort. If you want to sort after setting the comparator
     * you need to explicitly invoke
     * <code>sort</code>.
     *
     * @param column the index of the column the <code>Comparator</code> is to
     * be used for, in terms of the underlying model
     * @param comparator the <code>Comparator</code> to use
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if <code>column</code> is outside the
     * range of the underlying model
     */
    public void setComparator(int column, Comparator<?> comparator) {
        checkColumn(column);
        if (comparators == null) {
            comparators = new Comparator[getModelWrapper().getColumnCount()];
        }
        comparators[column] = comparator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the
     * <code>Comparator</code> for the specified column. This will return
     * <code>null</code> if a
     * <code>Comparator</code> has not been specified for the column.
     *
     * @param column the column to fetch the <code>Comparator</code> for, in
     * terms of the underlying model
     * @return the <code>Comparator</code> for the specified column
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if column is outside the range of the
     * underlying model
     */
    public Comparator<?> getComparator(int column) {
        checkColumn(column);
        if (comparators != null) {
            return comparators[column];
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Returns the Comparator to use during sorting.  Where as
    // getComparator() may return null, this will never return null.
    private Comparator getComparator0(int column) {
        Comparator comparator = getComparator(column);
        if (comparator != null) {
            return comparator;
        }
        // This should be ok as useToString(column) should have returned
        // true in this case.
        return Collator.getInstance();
    }

    private RowFilter.Entry<M, I> getFilterEntry(int modelIndex) {
        if (filterEntry == null) {
            filterEntry = new FilterEntry();
        }
        filterEntry.modelIndex = modelIndex;
        return filterEntry;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int getViewRowCount() {
        if (viewToModel != null) {
            // When filtering this may differ from getModelWrapper().getRowCount()
            return viewToModel.length;
        }
        return getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int getModelRowCount() {
        return getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
    }

    private void allChanged() {
        modelToView = null;
        viewToModel = null;
        comparators = null;
        isSortable = null;
        if (isUnsorted()) {
            // Keys are already empty, to force a resort we have to
            // call sort
            sort();
        } else {
            setSortKeys(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void modelStructureChanged() {
        allChanged();
        modelRowCount = getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void allRowsChanged() {
        modelRowCount = getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
        sort();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void rowsInserted(int firstRow, int endRow) {
        checkAgainstModel(firstRow, endRow);
        int newModelRowCount = getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
        if (endRow >= newModelRowCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid range");
        }
        modelRowCount = newModelRowCount;
        if (shouldOptimizeChange(firstRow, endRow)) {
            rowsInserted0(firstRow, endRow);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void rowsDeleted(int firstRow, int endRow) {
        checkAgainstModel(firstRow, endRow);
        if (firstRow >= modelRowCount || endRow >= modelRowCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid range");
        }
        modelRowCount = getModelWrapper().getRowCount();
        if (shouldOptimizeChange(firstRow, endRow)) {
            rowsDeleted0(firstRow, endRow);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void rowsUpdated(int firstRow, int endRow) {
        checkAgainstModel(firstRow, endRow);
        if (firstRow >= modelRowCount || endRow >= modelRowCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid range");
        }
        if (getSortsOnUpdates()) {
            if (shouldOptimizeChange(firstRow, endRow)) {
                rowsUpdated0(firstRow, endRow);
            }
        } else {
            sorted = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void rowsUpdated(int firstRow, int endRow, int column) {
        checkColumn(column);
        rowsUpdated(firstRow, endRow);
    }

    private void checkAgainstModel(int firstRow, int endRow) {
        if (firstRow > endRow || firstRow < 0 || endRow < 0
                || firstRow > modelRowCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid range");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the specified row should be included.
     */
    private boolean include(int row) {
        RowFilter<? super M, ? super I> filterInclude = getRowFilter();
        if (filterInclude != null) {
            return filterInclude.include(getFilterEntry(row));
        }
        // null filterInclude, always include the row.
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private int compare(int model1, int model2) {
        int column;
        SortOrder sortOrder;
        Object v1, v2;
        int result;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < cachedSortKeys.length; counter++) {
            column = cachedSortKeys[counter].getColumn();
            sortOrder = cachedSortKeys[counter].getSortOrder();
            if (sortOrder == SortOrder.UNSORTED) {
                result = model1 - model2;
            } else {
                // v1 != null && v2 != null
                if (useToString[column]) {
                    v1 = getModelWrapper().getStringValueAt(model1, column);
                    v2 = getModelWrapper().getStringValueAt(model2, column);
                } else {
                    v1 = getModelWrapper().getValueAt(model1, column);
                    v2 = getModelWrapper().getValueAt(model2, column);
                }
                // Treat nulls as < then non-null
                if (v1 == null) {
                    if (v2 == null) {
                        result = 0;
                    } else {
                        result = -1;
                    }
                } else if (v2 == null) {
                    result = 1;
                } else {
                    result = sortComparators[counter].compare(v1, v2);
                }
                if (sortOrder == SortOrder.DESCENDING) {
                    result *= -1;
                }
            }
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        // If we get here, they're equal. Fallback to model order.
        return model1 - model2;
    }

    /**
     * Whether not we are filtering/sorting.
     */
    private boolean isTransformed() {
        return (viewToModel != null);
    }

    /**
     * Insets new set of entries.
     *
     * @param toAdd the Rows to add, sorted
     * @param current the array to insert the items into
     */
    private void insertInOrder(List<Row> toAdd, Row[] current) {
        int last = 0;
        int index;
        int max = toAdd.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            index = Arrays.binarySearch(current, toAdd.get(i));
            if (index < 0) {
                index = -1 - index;
            }
            System.arraycopy(current, last,
                    viewToModel, last + i, index - last);
            viewToModel[index + i] = toAdd.get(i);
            last = index;
        }
        System.arraycopy(current, last, viewToModel, last + max,
                current.length - last);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if we should try and optimize the processing of the
     * <code>TableModelEvent</code>. If this returns false, assume the event was
     * dealt with and no further processing needs to happen.
     */
    private boolean shouldOptimizeChange(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        if (!isTransformed()) {
            // Not transformed, nothing to do.
            return false;
        }
        if (!sorted || (lastRow - firstRow) > viewToModel.length / 10) {
            // We either weren't sorted, or to much changed, sort it all
            sort();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void rowsInserted0(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        int[] oldViewToModel = getViewToModelAsInts(viewToModel);
        int i;
        int delta = (lastRow - firstRow) + 1;
        List<Row> added = new ArrayList<>(delta);

        // Build the list of Rows to add into added
        for (i = firstRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
            if (include(i)) {
                added.add(new Row(this, i));
            }
        }

        // Adjust the model index of rows after the effected region
        int viewIndex;
        for (i = modelToView.length - 1; i >= firstRow; i--) {
            viewIndex = modelToView[i];
            if (viewIndex != -1) {
                viewToModel[viewIndex].modelIndex += delta;
            }
        }

        // Insert newly added rows into viewToModel
        if (added.size() > 0) {
            Collections.sort(added);
            Row[] lastViewToModel = viewToModel;
            viewToModel = new Row[viewToModel.length + added.size()];
            insertInOrder(added, lastViewToModel);
        }

        // Update modelToView
        createModelToView(getModelWrapper().getRowCount());
        setModelToViewFromViewToModel(true);

        // Notify of change
        fireRowSorterChanged(oldViewToModel);
    }

    private void rowsDeleted0(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        int[] oldViewToModel = getViewToModelAsInts(viewToModel);
        int removedFromView = 0;
        int i;
        int viewIndex;

        // Figure out how many visible rows are going to be effected.
        for (i = firstRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
            viewIndex = modelToView[i];
            if (viewIndex != -1) {
                removedFromView++;
                viewToModel[viewIndex] = null;
            }
        }

        // Update the model index of rows after the effected region
        int delta = lastRow - firstRow + 1;
        for (i = modelToView.length - 1; i > lastRow; i--) {
            viewIndex = modelToView[i];
            if (viewIndex != -1) {
                viewToModel[viewIndex].modelIndex -= delta;
            }
        }

        // Then patch up the viewToModel array
        if (removedFromView > 0) {
            Row[] newViewToModel = new Row[viewToModel.length
                    - removedFromView];
            int newIndex = 0;
            int last = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < viewToModel.length; i++) {
                if (viewToModel[i] == null) {
                    System.arraycopy(viewToModel, last,
                            newViewToModel, newIndex, i - last);
                    newIndex += (i - last);
                    last = i + 1;
                }
            }
            System.arraycopy(viewToModel, last,
                    newViewToModel, newIndex, viewToModel.length - last);
            viewToModel = newViewToModel;
        }

        // Update the modelToView mapping
        createModelToView(getModelWrapper().getRowCount());
        setModelToViewFromViewToModel(true);

        // And notify of change
        fireRowSorterChanged(oldViewToModel);
    }

    private void rowsUpdated0(int firstRow, int lastRow) {
        int[] oldViewToModel = getViewToModelAsInts(viewToModel);
        int i, j;
        int delta = lastRow - firstRow + 1;
        int modelIndex;
        int last;
        int index;

        if (getRowFilter() == null) {
            // Sorting only:

            // Remove the effected rows
            Row[] updated = new Row[delta];
            for (j = 0, i = firstRow; i <= lastRow; i++, j++) {
                updated[j] = viewToModel[modelToView[i]];
            }

            // Sort the update rows
            Arrays.sort(updated);

            // Build the intermediary array: the array of
            // viewToModel without the effected rows.
            Row[] intermediary = new Row[viewToModel.length - delta];
            for (i = 0, j = 0; i < viewToModel.length; i++) {
                modelIndex = viewToModel[i].modelIndex;
                if (modelIndex < firstRow || modelIndex > lastRow) {
                    intermediary[j++] = viewToModel[i];
                }
            }

            // Build the new viewToModel
            insertInOrder(Arrays.asList(updated), intermediary);

            // Update modelToView
            setModelToViewFromViewToModel(false);
        } else {
            // Sorting & filtering.

            // Remove the effected rows, adding them to updated and setting
            // modelToView to -2 for any rows that were not filtered out
            List<Row> updated = new ArrayList<>(delta);
            int newlyVisible = 0;
            int newlyHidden = 0;
            int effected = 0;
            for (i = firstRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
                if (modelToView[i] == -1) {
                    // This row was filtered out
                    if (include(i)) {
                        // No longer filtered
                        updated.add(new Row(this, i));
                        newlyVisible++;
                    }
                } else {
                    // This row was visible, make sure it should still be
                    // visible.
                    if (!include(i)) {
                        newlyHidden++;
                    } else {
                        updated.add(viewToModel[modelToView[i]]);
                    }
                    modelToView[i] = -2;
                    effected++;
                }
            }

            // Sort the updated rows
            Collections.sort(updated);

            // Build the intermediary array: the array of
            // viewToModel without the updated rows.
            Row[] intermediary = new Row[viewToModel.length - effected];
            for (i = 0, j = 0; i < viewToModel.length; i++) {
                modelIndex = viewToModel[i].modelIndex;
                if (modelToView[modelIndex] != -2) {
                    intermediary[j++] = viewToModel[i];
                }
            }

            // Recreate viewToModel, if necessary
            if (newlyVisible != newlyHidden) {
                viewToModel = new Row[viewToModel.length + newlyVisible
                        - newlyHidden];
            }

            // Rebuild the new viewToModel array
            insertInOrder(updated, intermediary);

            // Update modelToView
            setModelToViewFromViewToModel(true);
        }
        // And finally fire a sort event.
        fireRowSorterChanged(oldViewToModel);
    }

    private void checkColumn(int column) {
        if (column < 0 || column >= getModelWrapper().getColumnCount()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "column beyond range of TableModel");
        }
    }

    /**
     * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter.ModelWrapper</code> is responsible
     * for providing the data that gets sorted by
     * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter</code>. You normally do not interact
     * directly with
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code>. Subclasses of
     * <code>DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter</code> provide an implementation of
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code> wrapping another model. For example,
     * <code>TableRowSorter</code> provides a
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code> that wraps a
     * <code>TableModel</code>. <p>
     * <code>ModelWrapper</code> makes a distinction between values as
     * <code>Object</code>s and
     * <code>String</code>s. This allows implementations to provide a custom
     * string converter to be used instead of invoking
     * <code>toString</code> on the object.
     *
     * @param <M> the type of the underlying model
     * @param <I> the identifier supplied to the filterInclude
     * @since 1.6
     * @see RowFilter
     * @see RowFilter.Entry
     */
    protected abstract static class ModelWrapper<M, I> {

        /**
         * Creates a new
         * <code>ModelWrapper</code>.
         */
        protected ModelWrapper() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns the underlying model that this
         * <code>Model</code> is wrapping.
         *
         * @return the underlying model
         */
        public abstract M getModel();

        /**
         * Returns the number of columns in the model.
         *
         * @return the number of columns in the model
         */
        public abstract int getColumnCount();

        /**
         * Returns the number of rows in the model.
         *
         * @return the number of rows in the model
         */
        public abstract int getRowCount();

        /**
         * Returns the value at the specified index.
         *
         * @param row the row index
         * @param column the column index
         * @return the value at the specified index
         * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the indices are outside the
         * range of the model
         */
        public abstract Object getValueAt(int row, int column);

        /**
         * Returns the value as a
         * <code>String</code> at the specified index. This implementation uses
         * <code>toString</code> on the result from
         * <code>getValueAt</code> (making sure to return an empty string for
         * null values). Subclasses that override this method should never
         * return null.
         *
         * @param row the row index
         * @param column the column index
         * @return the value at the specified index as a <code>String</code>
         * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the indices are outside the
         * range of the model
         */
        public String getStringValueAt(int row, int column) {
            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);
            if (o == null) {
                return "";
            }
            String string = o.toString();
            if (string == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return string;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the identifier for the specified row. The return value of
         * this is used as the identifier for the
         * <code>RowFilter.Entry</code> that is passed to the
         * <code>RowFilter</code>.
         *
         * @param row the row to return the identifier for, in terms of the
         * underlying model
         * @return the identifier
         * @see RowFilter.Entry#getIdentifier
         */
        public abstract I getIdentifier(int row);
    }

    /**
     * RowFilter.Entry implementation that delegates to the ModelWrapper.
     * getFilterEntry(int) creates the single instance of this that is passed to
     * the Filter. Only call getFilterEntry(int) to get the instance.
     */
    private class FilterEntry extends RowFilter.Entry<M, I> {

        /**
         * The index into the model, set in getFilterEntry
         */
        int modelIndex;

        @Override
        public M getModel() {
            return getModelWrapper().getModel();
        }

        @Override
        public int getValueCount() {
            return getModelWrapper().getColumnCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValue(int index) {
            return getModelWrapper().getValueAt(modelIndex, index);
        }

        @Override
        public String getStringValue(int index) {
            /* Original code here was:
             * 
             * return getModelWrapper().getStringValueAt(modelIndex, index);
             */
            if (accentIndiferent) {
                return Normalizer.normalize((String) getModelWrapper().getStringValueAt(modelIndex, index), Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
            } else {
                return getModelWrapper().getStringValueAt(modelIndex, index);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public I getIdentifier() {
            return getModelWrapper().getIdentifier(modelIndex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Row is used to handle the actual sorting by way of Comparable. It will
     * use the sortKeys to do the actual comparison.
     */
    // NOTE: this class is static so that it can be placed in an array
    private static class Row implements Comparable<Row> {

        private DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter sorter;
        int modelIndex;

        public Row(DefaultRowSorterSpecialFilter sorter, int index) {
            this.sorter = sorter;
            modelIndex = index;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Row o) {
            return sorter.compare(modelIndex, o.modelIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, a helper class, `RowFilterSpecialFilter`. Source (`RowFilterSpecialFilter.java`):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javax.swing;

import java.text.Normalizer;

/**
 *
 * @author Miroslav
 */
public abstract class RowFilterSpecialFilter {

    public static <M, I> RowFilter<M, I> regexFilterAccentIndiferent(String regex) {
        return RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + Normalizer.normalize(regex, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));
    }

    public static <M, I> RowFilter<M, I> regexFilterAccentIndiferent(String regex, int... indices) {
        return RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + Normalizer.normalize(regex, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""), indices);
    }
}
```

Now, how to use the filter with the accent indiferent function?

Instead of attaching a `TableRowSorter<MyClassThatInheritsFromAbstractModel>` to the jTable via `setRowSorter` method, attach a `TableRowSorterSpecialFilter<MyClassThatInheritsFromAbstractModel>` to it via the same method.

Don't forget to set `accentIndiferent` property to `true`. A simple `myTableRowSorterSpecialFilterInstance.AccentIndiferent = true;` is enough;

The code that should be fired up to apply a filter is what follows, where `FilterText` is the string that's going to be the filter:

```
    RowFilter<ClientesTableModel, Object> rf;
    try {
        rf = RowFilterSpecialFilter.regexFilterAccentIndiferent("(?i)" + FilterText);
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

I've put so many sources to help to anyone that gets the same trouble that I had. I'm pretty sure that I've modified something else but I don't remember it, so, better to be sure and make a good contribution.

And... done!!!